# Joomla administration user level

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

In my website project, three people are assigned to write new articles for the website. They write their own articleS and cannot view their fellows' articles. We have one supervisor who is supposed to view, edit, and manage all articles.

Can Joomla! or any free extension make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core Joomla install does NOT do what you have requested but by adding a component called JUGA, you can easily configure exactly what you want.
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/backend-a-full-access-control/2587